# ionic function similar to angular-xeditable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app that the user can edit their profile information. I want to use the angular-xeditable, but the format does not seems like a phone app and I also want to add another ng-autoComplete  (https://github.com/wpalahnuk/ngAutocomplete) directive to the same textbox, so I was wondering if there is anything in IONIC that is similar to angular-xeditable?

Here is an example what I want to do.  http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/starter/

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not the exact solution. I found a work around to this. So the users can edit profile and save everything together with one button. So basically user can click edit profile information, and then go to a form with all their info prefilled by using ng-init I think and then when they save their profile, I change the variable in the backend. I hope this helps